# How to change item of array's position

Tags: rubymotion

I want to change the cell position from **2 to 7**

`ruby
    @dams.insert(2, @dams.delete_at(7))`

I got this error

```
sort_dams_screen.rb:29:in `on_cell_moved:': can't modify frozen/immutable array (RuntimeError)
```

How to acheive my goal in rubymotion

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to mutate an immutable array. Try something like this:

```
dams = @dams.mutableCopy
dams.insert(2, dams.delete_at(7))
@dams = dams
```